# Remote code execution vs local code execution

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, .net-3.5

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399410(v=vs.90).aspx

> If your database has thousands of rows of orders, you do not want to retrieve them all to process a small subset. In LINQ to SQL, the EntitySet(Of TEntity) class implements the IQueryable interface.

In my solution I opened EntitySet in reflector which gave me this:-

```
 public sealed class EntitySet<TEntity> : IList,
                                         ICollection,
                                         IList<TEntity>,
                                         ICollection<TEntity>,
                                         IEnumerable<TEntity>,
                                         IEnumerable,
                                         IListSource
```

IQueryable does not seem to be implemented, which is consistent with what I'm seeing with FK associations querying a local collection rather than the database. Is there a way to get FK associations to return `IQueryable` instead of `EntitySet`? Thanks